Proper use of select in select in jq
I have a file
[{
key: 'value',
key1:{
key:'value'
},
fields:[{
to:{
id:'value'
},
field:{
id:'value',
name:'value'
}
},
{key:'value'}]
}]

I need to find elements of initial array which have and array .fields[] which have .field.id=='status' and .to.id=="closed"
I ve tried [.changelog[] | select(.fields[]|select(.field.id=="status" and (.to.key=="closed" or .to.key=="done")))]
A mistake 'cannot iterate over null' apears. Apparently, i can use .changelog[].fields but i cant use .changelog[].fields[]

Apart from not being valid JSON (keys and string values need to be enclosed within double quotes), you have an array containing one object with keys key, key1, and fields. There's no changelog (which consequently evaluates to null), and .changelog[] rightfully fails with cannot iterate over null. What is your expected output for the input given? Did you mean something like map(.fields[] | select(.field.id == "value" and IN(.to.id; "value", "other")))? Demo

@pmf I am sorry for the confusion, here is the correct example of a dictionary that i am trying to filtrate. My expected output is there as well, in a real json i am trying to deal with, there are more elements in the initial array, but i only need the ones where  .changelog[].fields[].field.id=="status" and .changelog[].fields[].to.key=="closed". Say i need to get .changelog[].id from these elements. I am sorry again for the confusion.

It seems the problem lies in the environment i am working in, cause in jqplay i can do .changelog[].fields[] and in my environment it returns an error.
P.S. - I m still looking for a solution without opening an array in an array like [][], if it exists

Oh, i'm dumb: some of the elements of an array did not contain .fields at all or they were null, that's why a problem occured. I m sorry for being dumb


... .fields[] which have .field.id=='status' and .to.id=="closed"

Assuming the sample data is translated to JSON (*), the following query, which corresponds to these requirements, would work:
select(.[].fields[] | select(.field and .field.id=="status" and (.to.id == "closed")))

This is just one of several reasonable possibilities, but the key point is that since not all items in .fields[] have a key named "field", you cannot write a query that assumes they do.

(*) hjson will do the job.
